# How to check if a String contains close group brackets in Java

Tags: java, string, algorithm, stack

How to checks a string for correct grouping. For instance, the following groups are done correctly:

```
({})
[[]()]
[{()}]
```

The next are done incorrectly:

```
{(})
([]
[])
```

A correct string cannot close groups in the wrong order, open a group but fail to close it, or close a group before it is opened.

The input string that may contain any of the symbols "()" "{}" or "[]" to create groups. The output return `True` if the string is empty or otherwise grouped correctly, or `False` if it is grouped incorrectly.

May anyone give me some hint with this.

Comment: Use stack (deque) in Java.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a given string is balanced brackets string, recursively](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20506179/check-if-a-given-string-is-balanced-brackets-string-recursively)

Comment: Please mark the corresponding answer as _solution_ if it solves the problems from your question, this way future readers can easily find the solution right away.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main idea is to use a `Stack` to keep track of the next corresponding bracket expected.
The following code will work:

```
public boolean isValid(String s) {
    HashMap<Character, Character> closeBracketMap = new HashMap<Character, Character>();
    closeBracketMap.put(')', '(');
    closeBracketMap.put(']', '[');
    closeBracketMap.put('}', '{');
    HashSet<Character> openBracketSet = new HashSet<Character>(
        closeBracketMap.values());
    Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();

    char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        char cur = chars[i];
        if (openBracketSet.contains(cur)) {
            stack.push(cur);
        } else { // close brackets
            if (stack.isEmpty()) {
                return false;
            }
            if (closeBracketMap.get(cur) != stack.peek()) {
                return false;
            }
            stack.pop();
        }
    }

    return stack.isEmpty();
}
```

Comment: Looks very complicated :0

Comment: @KickButtowski It's not too complex for optimal run-time of `O(n)` :)

Comment: Begging reputation is not permissible at all.

Comment: I've up-voted before he commented, so my upvote was in good faith. Admin can probably check the timestamps

Answer (score 0):

I really don't want to use stack, after trying something around. Here is my solution. I think this is very clear and simple:

```
public class Groups{
  public static boolean groupCheck(String s) {
    int len;
    do {
      len = s.length();
      s = s.replace("()", "");
      s = s.replace("{}", "");
      s = s.replace("[]", "");
    } while (len != s.length());
    return s.length() == 0;
  }
}
```

That means we will remove one by one bracket.

For example: `String s = "[]({[]()})"` (len = 10; s.length() = 10) it will remove "[]", "[]", "()". Then s = "({})" (s.length() = 4) it will continue to remove "{}". Then s = "()" (s.length() = 2), it will continue to remove "()". Then s = "" (s.length() = 0).  It will break the loop because ( (len == 10) != (s.length() == 0) ). Then we will be able to check it is true. :)

Comment: The worst case run-time of your solution is `O(n^2)`, n the length of string, as each `replace()` costs `O(n)`